# Getting a different result for when rotating a vector with a euler angles and quaternion

Tags: matlab, rotation

I am trying to rotate a vector in MATLAB in the the following order:

1. Rotate along x-axis by 30 degrees
2. Rotate along y-axis by 30 degrees
3. Rotate along z-axis by 30 degrees

This is my code for Euler Angles to rotation matrix:

```
eul = [pi/6 pi/6 pi/6];
rotmZYX = eul2rotm(eul)
rotmXYZ = eul2rotm(eul, "XYZ")
r = [0 0 5];
f1 = rotmZYX*r
f2 = rotmXYZ*r
```

I get the following result:

[image: Result from Euler Angles]

This is my code for quaternion rotation:

```
z = [cosd(15) 0 0 sind(15)];
y = [cosd(15) 0 sind(15) 0];
x = [cosd(15) sind(15) 0 0];
r = [0 0 5];

q1 = quatmultiply(z,y)
qf1 = quatmultiply(q1, x)
r1 = quatrotate(qf1,r);
```

I get the following result:

[image: Quaternion rotation result]

What I don't understand is why are all the rotations producing a different result? Why does my quaternion rotation not match any of the euler angle rotations?